# MS-Access VBA If statment is returning the same results no matter if the condition has been met or not

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to make sure that the user does not enter more downtime than they have available. The main form has boxes to enter their start and end time. Then, I have a box that calculates the available time. I have verified that this works.
 In a subform, the user enters information about any downtime they had and the minutes they were not working. My `If` statement should say "If the user is trying to enter a number that is larger than the time that is available then stop them and make them fix it".

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub MinutesDown_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If (Forms("DailyInput").Controls("Txtuptime") > Me.MinutesDown.Text) Then

        MsgBox (" You just entered more downtime than was available. Please check your downtime.")
        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are comparing text. In text `"123" < "23"` is evaluated as `TRUE`

Comment: Don't use .Text property.

Comment: Consider `Forms!DailyInput.Txtuptime` or `Me.Parent.Txtuptime` or to provoke intellisense popup tips `Form_DailyInput.Txtuptime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *Value* property:

```
Private Sub MinutesDown_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me.Parent!Txtuptime.Value > Me!MinutesDown.Value Then

        MsgBox "You just entered more downtime than was available. Please check your downtime."
        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This was perfect. I can't believe I didn't catch that myself. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `If` statement compare Numeric values, rather than Text Strings:

```
Private Sub MinutesDown_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If (Cdbl(Forms("DailyInput").Controls("Txtuptime")) > Cdbl(Me.MinutesDown.Text)) Then

        MsgBox (" You just entered more downtime than was available. Please check your downtime.")
        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```